# Yii - find all by composite key

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

How do I find all by primary key? I don't want to specify the start and end dates as they aren't relevant when opening within booking form

```
$bookingRoom = BookingRoom::model()->findByPk(array('roomId' => 1, 'bookingId' => 1, 'startDate' => '20140619', 'endDate' => '20140620'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `findAllByAttributes()` option:

```
$bookingRoom = BookingRoom::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('roomId' => 1, 'bookingId' => 1, 'startDate' => '20140619', 'endDate' => '20140620'));
```

If you don't want the startDate and endDate included remove it from the array.

Here is the documentation: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByAttributes-detail

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 $id = // code to set the id
 $bookingRoom = BookingRoom::model()->findAllByPk($id);
```